# Adding new column in between columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we add new column in-between columns to the table by drag and drop method with javascript/jQuery? I am grateful to know simple logical steps/script to achieve that!

Comment: new what ?? new stone  ???

Comment: @Baadshah No. new microwave.

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried. I'm sure you can look up in Google how to add an element into the DOM.

Comment: In pure javascript http://www.danvk.org/wp/dragtable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need drag and drop, you will want to use jQuery and jQueryUI (see [.draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [.droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)).

Adding and removing elements can be done using the vanilla jQ functions [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) and [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Please note that the total solution to your problem is not a simple one-liner, you will have to use the tools provided to make your own script work.

Comment: Yes it looks better to use such a useful plugin lib like jq-ui to start this. Thanks.